# Error with command line "rails server" on mac

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Whenever I use the command "rails server" in mac terminal, it prompts this error:

```
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- rubygems/format (LoadError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/source.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:14:in `initialize'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:6:in `new'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:6:in `evaluate'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/definition.rb:17:in `build'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler.rb:138:in `definition'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler.rb:126:in `load'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler.rb:110:in `setup'
    from /Users/martindureja/Desktop/rails_projects/first_app/config/boot.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from script/rails:5:in `<main>'
```

Comment: I dont know what the error is saying but my first step is to try bundle install.

Comment: Whenever I try to install bundler it gives me the error : You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory.

Comment: Are you using Compass?

Comment: I am not aware of Compass. Can you elaborate on it please? And how it can help me?

Comment: what about `sudo bundle install` ?

Comment: Sorry, I was searching /core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require' then all of the top solutions were saying to reinstall Compass, but since you are not using it, it is probably another gem that is causing the error for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have permission errors when trying to install your gems. If you don't want to worry about this in the future, use RVM.

https://rvm.io/